# How can I redirect to another page in Servlet using response.sendRedirect() method?

Tags: redirect, servlets

```
**loginServlet.java**

package com.anil.apps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        String uid=request.getParameter("userid");
        String password=request.getParameter("pwd");

        if(uid.equals("Anil")&&password.equals("missinlx")){
            //out.println("welcome "+uid);
            response.sendRedirect("welcomeUser?userid="+uid);
        }
        else{
            out.println("invalid username or password");
        }
    }

}






**WelcomeUserServlet.java**

package com.anil.apps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class WelcomeUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html><body><h1>Welcome " +uid+ "</h1></body></html>");
    }

}
```

what is wrong with my code?? I want to redirect the page to welcomeUser.java page using response.sendRedirect() method.
As I am new to servlet please help me out of it. please tell me the whole format for the page redirection in Servlets.

Comment: What is not working? Your usage of `sendRedirect` looks okay to me.

Comment: I don't know but my IDE is showing error.

Comment: Like a syntax error? What does it say?

Comment: out.println("<html><body><h1>Welcome " +uid+ "</h1></body></html>"); it shows error in this line

Comment: it says create a local variable uid

Answer (score 0):

`GET` parameters are not turned in to variables automatically. You need to add this to the top of your `doGet` method in the `WelcomeUserServlet`:

```
String uid = request.getParameter("userId");
```

Making that class look like this:

```
public class WelcomeUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uid = request.getParameter("userId");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html><body><h1>Welcome " +uid+ "</h1></body></html>");
    }

}
```

Comment: but I want to use the uid of the loginServlet.java to use in the WelcomeUserServlet.

Comment: Yes, but variables aren't shared between requests. You are already passing it as a parameter when you say `?userid="+uid` you need to get it in your other servlet.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong argument for the sendRedirect method

You should use a complete path like

```
response.sendRedirect("some/path/here/to/"+welcomeUser?userid="+uid)
```

Or better

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL(response.getContextPath()+"welcomeUser?userid="+uid))
```

Or use a request dispatcher which knows the structure of your project and does not need a full path

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("welcomeUser?userid="+uid).forward(request,response)
```